# How can I iterate through a map in in state to create React components?

Tags: reactjs, dictionary, react-hooks

I am trying to create an array of objects and then create an series of React components from each one. The array is set in the state using Hooks.

```
const [busy, setBusy] = useState([
    {id: 1, timeState: "freeTime"},
    {id: 2, timeState: "freeTime"},
    {id: 3, timeState: "freeTime"}
```

])

I then make a function that creates the components.

```
const TimeBlocks = busy.map((busy) => 
    <Box key={busy.id} as={busy.timeState}>{busy.timeState}</Box>
);
```

Then in the return statement of the parent component I call
    `return ( <TimeBlocks /> )`

When I try to run, I get the error `Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got object.`

I understand that I need to pass in a function here but from following documentation on iterating in this way, they are all in this format. How can I turn this into a usable function or do this in another way that works? Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you add more of your code?

Comment: @Doc-Han sorry I left out the return statement. updated.

Comment: Is `Box` coming from a UI library (e.g. Material UI)?

Comment: @helloitsjoe Yes, its coming from Grommet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're assigning an array to `TimeBlocks`, when you should be assigning a function that returns an array.

```
const TimeBlocks = () => busy.map((busy) => 
    <Box key={busy.id} as={busy.timeState}>{busy.timeState}</Box>
);
```

This will define `TimeBlocks` as a functional component, and you can use it like you have in your example `<TimeBlocks />`.

Edit: You asked about adding logic to the function. The code I provided uses two implicit returns (one that returns the result of `.map`, and one that returns the `Box` component), but you can easily modify it to add some logic in either place, just add enclosing brackets and a `return` statement:

```
const TimeBlocks = () => {
  // logic here
  return busy.map((busy) => {
    // and/or logic here
      return <Box key={busy.id} as={busy.timeState}>{busy.timeState}</Box>
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: This was the problem. Works perfect now. Thank you!

Comment: Sure thing, no problem!

Comment: if you don't mind answering,  if I wanted to add some logic to this function, like an if statement, would it work in this current state or does it need to be refactored again?